# Testing payable functions with truffle console - where do you input msg.value?

Tags: truffle, gas, payable

Trying to test my token contract using truffle console + ganache, lets say I have a payable function someFunc(string _string, uint256 _int), how would I call it with arguments "hello", 100 and msg.value = 2 eth?

As a side q, where does the gas eth come from? is it taken from msg.value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
myContract.someFunc("hello",100,{value: 2000000000000000000}).then(...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: he asks for msg.value=2eth not 100 weis.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the eth gas comes from the sender, separate from the amount sent in the transaction value. Hope that can help you 2 years later :)